# How to make java.lang.Object.clone public?

Tags: java, jvm

Specifically: how can I modify `java.lang.Object.clone` so that the JVM doesn't squawk when bytecode calls it?

Comment: why do you want it? Please explain problem you want to solve.

Comment: Like @AlexR says, you seem to give us the syndrom, not the root cause. So, when (or how) does that Object#clone method call appears in your stack ?

Comment: I want to have a standard copy method. Clone's behavior makes it work nicely except that the JVM squawks due to it being protected. This is the root cause, not the symptom.

Comment: You can edit the source for Object and make it public.  This is likely to be a very bad idea.  Why are you trying to use `clone()` at all? (Even using clone() can be considered a bad idea)

Comment: @sparkleshy You cannot redistribute the reeult. It is a violation of the terms of the Java License. It is pointless.

Comment: @EJP: But I _can_ write a snippet of code that modifies any rt.jar in this way. It is not pointless.

Comment: @sparkleshy and can you really distribute that? Are your customers going to accept it? Is it valid under the licence? It's not just a matter of what code you can write.

Comment: @EJP: Stop it with the FUD. All I have to do is extract `Object.class`, change a byte, repackage it in a jar, and add a parameter to `java.exe`. (modifying `rt.jar` works too, but this is easier)

Comment: @sparkleshy There is no 'doubt' about it. What you propose here is contrary to the Java license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter Lawrey's comment gave the idea of editing `rt.jar`. This works. It is also utterly harmless.

(changed access modifier code `0x0104` to `0x0101` at the right place in `rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class`)

Similarly, one can construct an `rtplus.jar` containing just the modified class file and use `-Xbootclasspath/p:rtplus.jar` to have `java` use that version instead. (and yes, EJP, we can't distribute that `rtplus.jar` but it's quite easy to generate programmatically)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this will not work. Some classes in rt.jar (like `java.awt.font.TextLayout`) override `clone()` and keep it protected. If you change `Object.clone()` to be public, such subclasses will probably fail to load, because by the Java language rules, a subclass cannot override a method with a more restrictive access modifier.

Comment: @TedHopp: Remember, this question is about the JVM, not the Java language. On the JVM, this works; I tested it. (note: you have to call `Object.clone`, not `Thread.clone`; the latter does throw an `IllegalAccessError` (ofc, calling `Object.clone` has exactly the same effect since it's virtual))

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify `java.lang.Object.clone()`. You can override `clone()` to make it a public method in any class you define, although it is fairly useless to do so unless the class (or some class in its hierarchy) is declared to implement the `Cloneable` interface.

```
public class MyClass implements Cloneable {
    public Object clone() {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

The other usual approach to copying is to define a copy constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        // standard default constructor
    }

    public MyClass(MyClass other) {
        // copy constructor -- initialize from values in other
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer *is* useful. It exactly explains how to work with `clone()`

Comment: @AlexR: I didn't ask how to work with clone() within the normal java language. This answer answers a different question than the one I asked: it is not useful.

Comment: @sparkleshy - The answer may not be what you want (`java.lang.Object.clone()` cannot be modified), but it seems silly to shoot the messenger. If you want to copy an instance of `Object`, what's wrong with `new Object()`? If you want to copy an instance of a subclass, then just override `clone()`, make it public, and you have what you want.

Comment: @TedHopp: And if I want to copy an instance of an entirely unknown class?

Comment: @sparkleshy - If you don't know anything about the class, it could be meaningless, or even dangerous, to copy the instance. (What would you do with a copy of a `ServerSocket`, for instance, other than possibly screw up the socket by having two instances responding to an incoming packet?) What are you actually trying to accomplish? There are very good reasons why some classes do not implement `Cloneable` or provide a copy constructor.

Comment: @TedHopp: So? When it fails to implement Cloneable or provide a clone() override, it'll throw me an exception instead of being dangerously copied.

Comment: @sparkleshy - And why would it be useful to change a compile-time error into a run-time exception? Also, as I pointed out in a comment to your own answer, what are you going to do about other classes that override `clone()` and keep it protected? (You won't be able to use classes `java.lang.Enum` or `java.lang.Thread`, most likely.)

Comment: @TedHopp: Because it _also_ lets me clone (without the overhead of reflection) objects that can be cloned. Also, as I replied to the comment to my own answer, I'm going to do absolutely nothing. They work just fine.